# How to create ambient declarations for Twilio global JS library in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, global, declaration

I'm using [Twilio.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js) library on my application (not Twilio Node) and there's no module nor typings for this library available. There's only a `Twilio` global variable available that one can use.

The simplest ambient declaration one can have to avoid errors in the IDE is this:

```
declare const Twilio: any;
```

But I want to go a little bit further and for that I've been reading TypeScript handbook and few other resources. I've taken especially attention to [this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#ambient-namespaces).

And here's what I have so far:

```
declare const Twilio: Twilio.Base;

declare namespace Twilio {

    export interface Base {
        Device: Device;
    }

    export interface Device {
        ready(handler: DeviceCallback): void;
    }

    export interface DeviceCallback {
        (device: Device): void;
    }

}
```

This is working, but it's just a sample, it's not complete. As an example, it suffices for now :)

But my question is three-fold:

1. Given the short sample above, would you do anything differently?
2. If I remove the `export` keyword from all interfaces, it still works. Should I still leave it? What does it do?
3. Given the usage `Twilio.Device.ready(this.handleTwilioDeviceReady.bind(this));`, IDEs give me the following when hovering my mouse over:

   - `Twilio`: `const Twilio: Twilio.Base`
   - `Twilio.Device`: `(property) Twilio.Base.Device: Twilio.Device`
   - `Twilio.Device.ready`: `(method) Twilio.Device.ready(handler: Twilio.DeviceCallback): void`
   - How can I get rid of `Twilio.Base` showing up in the IDE and instead show:

     - `Twilio`: `const Twilio: Twilio`
     - `Twilio.Device`: `(property) Twilio.Device: Twilio.Device`

Comment: Looks like there is a type definition for Twilio available as `@types/twilio` via npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/twilio

Comment: @Seamus That's for [Twilio Node.js helper library](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/), not for the one I'm using. Forgot to link that...

Comment: Just fyi, `Twilio.Device.ready(() => this.handleTwilioDeviceReady());` would be more idiomatic TypeScript :)

Comment: @JKillian Thanks for the suggestion. I'd prefer something more like [autobin-decorator](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator) though, but I'm having an [issue](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator/issues/43) getting it to work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a  look at the API and I think the below should be a good starting point as an ambient declaration file.

```
declare namespace Twilio {

    class Connection {
        // Constructor does not appear to be available to user.
        private constructor();
        // Add Connection Methods and Properties Here
    }

    // Not immediately clear if Twilio.Device is a class or not.
    interface IDevice {
        setup(token, options);
        ready(handler);
        offline(handler);
        incoming(handler);
        connect(params) : Connection;
        // Add Remainder of Twilio.Device properties here.
    }

    /**
     * Twilio.Device appears to be a singleton object that 
     * you don't instantiate yourself. You can use
     * the below to declare its presence.
     */
    let Device : IDevice;
}
```

A few more notes:

```
declare const Twilio: Twilio.Base;
```

This is made redundant by the following namespace declaration, which has the effect of declaring the presence of a plain old JS object with the name and members you've declared.

Export doesn't *appear* to have any function when declaring ambient classes/namespaces. It's only necessary if you're declaring a module with a default export member, or if you're writing a TS file and need to declare which classes and interfaces will be publicly accessible.

EDIT : Callback Type for Device.Ready

`IDevice` has the `ready` method, which accepts an function argument that's passed an `IDevice` object, and isn't expected to return anything. The type signature for such a function is:

```
(device : IDevice) => void;
```

An inline declaration would be:

```
ready((device : IDevice) => void) : void;
```

Given that you're going to reuse this callback type a few times, you should create a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and then refer to it like so:

```
type DeviceCallback = (device : IDevice) => void;

interface IDevice {
    ...
    ready(handler: DeviceCallback) : void;
    offline(handler : DeviceCallback) : void;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for :) I do have 2 follow up questions, one probably requires a new SO question... As an example, given the Twilio documentation for this: `.ready( handler(device) )` how would you properly declare this function? I see two options: **a)** `ready(handler: Function): void` or **b)** `ready(handler: (device: IDevice) => void): void`. What would be your recommendation? Is there a **c)** alternative?

Comment: My second follow up question needs more text and better examples, do you mind if I create a new question and link it back here for you to take a look? You seem to know your way around TS declaration files and it looks like there isn't too many people with that kind of knowledge around SO.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral sure thing! Do that and I'll answer both :)

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42398170/40480 in the mean time, if you could answer me on the **a)** question above, that would be great. This is just a matter of preference I suppose, so an additional question isn't needed, or do you want one?

Comment: @RicardoAmaral I've amended my answer with the question for the handler with the C option :)

Comment: Done, thanks very much. I'll award your bounty when allowed :)