# How to declare global NodeJS variables within my ambient declaration file?

Tags: node.js, typescript, namespaces, global, declaration

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42317942/40480).

Given the answer on that question, let's say I have the following ambient declaration file:

```
declare namespace Twilio {
    interface IDevice {
        ready(handler: Function): void;
    }

    let Device: IDevice;
}
```

This is working nicely on my application `.ts` files, `Twilio.Device.ready` is fully recognized. But I have my unit tests running with Jest and AFAIK, they run on a NodeJS environment.

As an over simplified mock on my tests I have this (which are `.ts` files too):

```
global.Twilio = {
     Device: {
         ready: () => {},
         offline: () => {},
         error: () => {},
     }
};
```

But this `Twilio` instance is not recognized. I can fix that by adding something like below to a `.d.ts` file:

```
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {
            Twilio: any;
        }
    }
}

export = {}; // This is needed otherwise `declare global` won't work
```

However, I can't have this piece of code on the same file as the `declare namespace Twilio` I first mentioned. They need to be on separate files, otherwise `global.Twilio` on my tests will be recognized but `Twilio.Device` on my code won't.

So my question is, how can I get both instances of `Twilio` to be recognized in the app code and in the tests code?

And as a bonus question, it would be nice if I could use the `Twilio` namespace declaration, somehow, as the type of the NodeJS `Twilio` global instead of `any`.

## **EDIT:**

After a nice chat with Richard Seviora, discussing all my issues, I ended up with the following `twilio.d.ts` file for my project:

```
/**
 * Namespace declaration for the Twilio.js library global variable.
 */
declare namespace Twilio {

    type DeviceCallback = (device : IDevice) => void;
    type ConnectionCallback = (connection : IConnection) => void;
    type ErrorCallback = (error : IError) => void;

    interface IConnection {
        parameters: IConnectionParameters;
    }

    interface IConnectionParameters {
        From?: string;
        To?: string;
    }

    interface IDevice {
        cancel(handler: ConnectionCallback): void;
        connect(params: IConnectionParameters): IConnection;
        disconnect(handler: ConnectionCallback): void;
        error(handler: ErrorCallback): void;
        incoming(handler: ConnectionCallback): void;
        offline(handler: DeviceCallback): void;
        ready(handler: DeviceCallback): void;
        setup(token: string, params: ISetupParameters): void;
    }

    interface IError {
        message?: string;
        code?: number;
        connection?: IConnection;
    }

    interface ISetupParameters {
        closeProtection: boolean;
    }

    let Device: IDevice;

}

/**
 * Augment the Node.js namespace with a global declaration for the Twilio.js library.
 */
declare namespace NodeJS {

    interface Global {
        Twilio: {
            // Partial type intended for test execution only!
            Device: Partial<Twilio.IDevice>;
        };
    }

}
```

Hopefully others find this question and Richard's answer below insightful (since the declarations documentation is kinda lacking).

Thanks again Richard for all your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely an interesting question. The problem is that the ambient file asserts that `Twilio.Device` exists, and so anything like a global declaration needs to take that into account.

It turned out being rather simple to solve. There was no need to extend the declaration file or create another one. Given the declaration file you provided, all you need to do include the following in your test setup:

```
namespace Twilio {
    Device = {
        setup: function () { },
        ready: function () { },
        offline: function () { },
        incoming: function () { },
        connect: function (params): Twilio.Connection { return null },
        error: function () { }
    }
}
```

Because we declared `let Twilio.Device : IDevice`, we also permitted consumers to assign `Twilio.Device` at later date. This would not be possible if we declared `const Twilio.Device : IDevice`.

However, we couldn't just say:

```
Twilio.Device = { ... }
```

Because doing so required the `Twilio` namespace to exist, which is something that we had asserted was the case when we said `declare namespace Twilio`. This Typescript would compile successfully, but the compiled JS took the existence of the ambient `Twilio` variable as granted and therefore failed.

TypeScript also doesn't allow you to assign values to an existing namespace so we couldn't do:

```
const Twilio = {}; // Or let for that matter.
Twilio.Device = {...}
```

However, since TypeScript namespace declarations merge in the compiled JS, wrapping the assignment in the Twilio namespace would instantiate `Twilio` (if it doesn't already exist) and then assign `Device`, while all respecting the type rules stated in the ambient file.

```
namespace Twilio {
    Device = {
        // All properties need to be stubbed.
        setup: function () { },
        ready: function () { },
        offline: function () { },
        incoming: function () { },
        connect: function (params): Twilio.Connection { return null },
        error: function () { }
    }
}

beforeEach(() => {
    // Properties/mocks will need to be reset as the namespace declaration only runs once.
    Twilio.Device.setup = () => {return null;};
})

test('adds stuff', () => {
    expect(Twilio.Device.setup(null, null)).toBeNull()
})
```

This all assumes that your test files have access to the declaration file. If not you'll need to include it through `tsconfig.json`, or reference it via `/// <references path="wherever"/>` directive.

### Edit 1

Corrected `beforeEach` in the example above to return null. Otherwise test would fail.

### Edit 2 - Extending NodeJS Global Declaration

I thought I should add why extending the `NodeJS.Global` interface isn't necessary.

When we make an ambient declaration, it is assumed to exist as part of the global context (and any child closures). Therefore, we don't need to extend `Global` with `Twilio` because `Twilio` is assumed to exist in the immediate context as well.

HOWEVER, this particular declaration method means that `global.Twilio` does not exist. I can declare:

```
namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        Twilio : {
            Device : Twilio.IDevice;
        };
    }
}
```

And this will provide type inference for the Device property of the `NodeJS.Global.Twilio` object, but there isn't a way to "share" namespaces in the same way we can types.

### EDIT 3 - Global Extension IS Necessary After All

After conversation, we came to the conclusion that extending `NodeJS.Global` is necessary because Jest does not share context between tests and the classes they're being executed in.

To allow us to modify the `NodeJS.Global` interface, we append the following to the definition file:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        Twilio: { Device: Partial<Twilio.IDevice> }
    }
}
```

This then enables:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    global.Twilio =
        {
            Device: {
                setup: function () { return null },
                ready: function () { },
                connect: function (params): Twilio.Connection { return null },
                error: function () { }
            }
        };
})
```

While this means that the `NodeJS.Global.Twilio` will not be identical to the `Twilio` namespace, it does permit to operate identically for the purpose of constructing tests.

Comment: Having that `namespace Twilio { Device= {} }` on my test files is not working for me. I get a `Cannot find name 'Device'.`.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral can you try referencing the declaration file via the triple-slash directive? If that doesn't work, can you include your `tsconfig.json` file(s) and project structure?

Comment: I believe you're missing something important here... Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40460395/40480 In my tests I currently have something like `global.Twilio = { Device: { ready: () => {} } };` wrapped in a `beforeAll` call. And this is working fine, I'm successfully mocking `Twilio.Device` and my tests pass. If I remove that, my tests fail. In other words, I need to use `global.Twilio` and not `Twilio` directly.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral can you provide a complete code sample? I have [this gist](https://gist.github.com/richseviora/7479889d210014b57d2d75da2b78ec16) and the test executes successfully for me.

Comment: In all honesty I'd like to avoid using the triple-slash directive. It feels like a hack. And I believe the TypeScript team did something on the latest TypeScript versions so that we don't need these annoying triple-slash directives.

Comment: I agree, but I wanted to make sure the issue isn't a type resolution issue. I've amended my answer with an example extension of the Global interface, which I think might be the way to go. I suspect the problem might be that the test context isn't the same context that your classes are executing in.

Comment: You don't really have the actual Twilio library, it's only a declaration, that's why it works. Forget about the Twilio namespace declaration we've created before for a second. Twilio.js is a library that exposes a global variable as `Twilio`. Inside my Jest tests, this variable is **accessible through `global.Twilio` only**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136394/discussion-between-richard-seviora-and-ricardo-amaral).

Comment: "I suspect the problem might be that the test context isn't the same context that your classes are executing in." Yeah, this is what I was trying to explain above. Sorry I wasn't more helpful.